# replacing string in list of lists python

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a list containing three separate lists:

```
James =     ['Alvin Kamara','Alex Collins','Michael Thomas',
          'Adam Thielen','Evan Engram','Lamar Miller']

Ben =   ['Todd Gurley II','Royce Freeman','Larry Fitzgerald',
        'Cooper Kupp','Benjamin Watson','Robby Anderson']

Chris =     ['Dion Lewis','Rex Burkhead','Julio Jones',
          'Keenan Allen','Zach Ertz','Demaryius Thomas']
```

I want to remove the text ' II', which if you look in the "Ben" list, would change 'Toddy Gurley II' to 'Todd Gurley'. My current attempt is this:

```
master_list = [James,Ben,Chris]

for owner in master_list:
    owner = [word.replace(' II','') for word in owner]

print(master_list[1])
```

But the output I get is:

```
['Todd Gurley II', 'Royce Freeman', 'Larry Fitzgerald', 'Cooper Kupp', 'Benjamin Watson', 'Robby Anderson']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your outer for loop, you update a copy of the `owner` variable, but do not replace it in the list. You can instead add the updated `owner` variable to a new list:

```
new_list = []
for owner in master_list:
    owner = [word.replace(' II','') for word in owner]
    new_list.append(owner)

print(new_list[1])

['Todd Gurley', 'Royce Freeman', 'Larry Fitzgerald', 'Cooper Kupp', 'Benjamin Watson', 'Robby Anderson']
```

Alternatively, you can use `enumerate()` over the owner list, in order to update the original `master_list` in place:

```
for i, owner in enumerate(master_list):
    owner = [word.replace(' II','') for word in owner]
    master_list[i] = owner

print(master_list[1])

['Todd Gurley', 'Royce Freeman', 'Larry Fitzgerald', 'Cooper Kupp', 'Benjamin Watson', 'Robby Anderson']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re`:

```
import re
print([re.sub('\sII$', '', i) for i in master_list[1]])
```

Output:

```
['Todd Gurley', 'Royce Freeman', 'Larry Fitzgerald', 'Cooper Kupp', 'Benjamin Watson', 'Robby Anderson']
```

Answer (score 1):

when you call `owner = [word.replace(' II','') for word in owner]`, you aren't updating `master_list`; you're modifying a copy of one of its elements.

You can either loop through and update `master_list` by making calls like

```
master_list[1] = [word.replace(' II','') for word in owner]
```

Or you could reference a new array:

```
new_master_list = []
for owner in master_list:
    new_master_list.append([word.replace(' II', '') for word in owner])

print(new_master_list[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

We can combine *enumerate* and *list comprehension* here and evaluate using the `[-2:]` position of our strings

```
l = [James, Ben, Chris]

for idx, item in enumerate(l):
    l[idx] = [i[:-3] if 'II' in i[-2:] else i for i in item]
```

> ```
> chrx@chrx:~/python/stackoverflow/9.22$ python3.7 uk.py
> [['Alvin Kamara', 'Alex Collins', 'Michael Thomas', 'Adam Thielen', 'Evan 
> Engram', 'Lamar Miller'], ['Todd Gurley', 'Royce
> Freeman', 'Larry Fitzgerald', 'Cooper Kupp', 'Benjamin Watson', 'Robby
> Anderson'], ['Dion Lewis', 'Rex Burkhead', 'Julio Jones', 'Keenan
> Allen', 'Zach Ertz', 'Demaryius Thomas']]
> ```